# How to load multiple result sets with one Entity Framework call?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

While learning Entity Framework 6, I have hit an obstacle and unsure how to handle a situation.  While making an API, a user may want a specific endpoint which requires access to multiple tables (Fake Entity, since it does not have a real table association). Below is some fake DbSets and a random class.

I am looking for a way to include all of these tables data (With Where Clauses) all in 1 query.  I was doing 3 separate calls, but I don't think this is the best way.

```
var anonObject = new AnonClass() 
{
    SometItems = await Context.Table1.Where(t => t.Something == true).ToListAsync();
    SometItems2 = await Context.Table2.Where(t => t.Something == true).ToListAsync();
    SometItems3 = await Context.Table3.Where(t => t.Something == true).ToListAsync();
};

DbSet<Table1> Table1;
DbSet<Table2> Table2;
DbSet<Table3> Table3;

public sealed AnonClass
{
    public IEnumerable<Table1> SomeItems;
    public IEnumerable<Table2> SomeItems2;
    public IEnumerable<Table3> SomeItems3;
}
```

Each of these are individual calls, I want them all in one.

Comment: I don't think that's possible. I mean, how would you get three separate result sets with one SQL query unless you could `UNION` them?

Comment: Can you make a view table and then select from there?

Comment: The code you've shown is just fine. Unlike EF6, EF Core itself uses multiple SQL queries for populating nested "collections" with data.

Comment: turn them into Tasks[] then at least they'll execute in parallel

Comment: @Brian That would be a terrible/dangerous idea in the land of Entity Framework. DbContext is not thread safe.

Comment: @Brian But EF Core won't allow that except if you also use 3 separate db context instances

Comment: Why make them ListAsync if you don't intend to execute the queries in parallel?

Comment: If you make DbContext Transient then each thread gets its own instance

Comment: @Brian I don't think you realise how this works. There is only one DbContext in the above code. You would need to inject 3 different contexts to make your idea work.

Comment: @Brian I believe there is still a bug in EF Core with doing Transient DbContext that will cause memory leaks. https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/7343

Comment: @KennethBean That issue was never confirmed, has been closed and is for a very old version of core. It also had nothing to do with DbContext being transient.

Comment: I was under the impression from most of what I read, that doing that (parallel requests) was a bad idea overall.  Are we saying that in newer EF we should?

Comment: Where did anyone suggest doing that?

Comment: @KennethBean No, we are saying your code is ok, and there is no way to do it with one db call (in EF Core). Forget it and move on.

Comment: Which version of EF you are using, is it EF core 2.1 and above?

Comment: @VatanSoni Correct, I think its 2.2.6 (Latest).

Comment: @IvanStoev Maybe there is a way to make the fake entity and then use .Include() the proper way?